# What character encoding am I seeing in my emails?

Tags: email, character-encoding

I'm getting emails occasionally that are having strange encoding issues. The quotation marks show up as `³example²`, and apostrophes show up as `that¹s`. I can't imagine that the other person actually meant to use those symbols, even though the email headers specify an encoding of `Windows-1252`. I'm using Thunderbird for Mac OSX, and I'm not sure what email client is being used to send these messages.

Answer (score 1):

These are the characters ` and angled double-quotes. In my experience, these are typically from OSX because it uses a specialized version of ISO-8859, that's what I recall reading when researching this issue a few months ago, if I find the reference I will add the link.

If the sender specifies UTF-8, this goes away.

Comment: I've been trying to find a reference on this, and have had no luck. Did you happen to find a reference to it? I found out about MacRoman, but that doesn't quite seem to explain the encoding issue.

Comment: I found it the reference where I originally read about this, it was this [blog post](http://cabbagesofdoom.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-stop-outlook-on-mac-osx.html)